# Равномерное увеличение изображения при анимации через CSS

Tags: css, css3

Как сделать, что бы картинка ровномерно увеличивалась? Сейчас она увеличивается вправо и вниз:

```
<img style="position:absolute; top:760px; left:160px;" src="assets/img/bas.png" alt="" class="img-header">
<img style="position:absolute; top:670px; left:1340px;" src="assets/img/fontan.png" alt="" class="img-header">
<img style="position:absolute; top:750px; left:870px;" src="assets/img/pog.png" alt="" class="img-header">
<img style="position:absolute; top:750px; left:1150px;" src="assets/img/drena.png" alt="" class="img-header">
<img style="position:absolute; top:430px; left:920px;" src="assets/img/col.png" alt="" class="img-header">
<img style="position:absolute; top:550px; left:200px;" src="assets/img/gibrid.png" alt="" class="img-header">

<style>
    .img-header {
        width:150px;
        transition: opacity 1s, width 1s;
        opacity:0;
    }
    .img-header:hover {
        width:250px;
        opacity:1;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать свойство `transform`. Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/fabric/0aywfjqq/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Для масштабирования изображения можно использовать свойство `transform` и функцию для него `scale(x, y)`, где первым аргументом будет масштаб по горизонтали, а второй по вертикали.

Пример:

```css
img {
  display: block;
  transition: transform 0.2s ease;
}
img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/" alt="">
```